# IEEE Float type to std_logic_vector conversion

Tags: floating-point, vhdl

I have a 2 D matrix where each element should be 64 bit std_logic_vector.

Now I want to store certain values into the matrix as shown in the below manner. How do I do that?
For example:

```
type a is array (0 to 10,0 to 10) of std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
signal a1: a;
a1(0,0) <= std_logic_vector( to_float64(12.23) );
```

Basically I dont know how to convert float64 to std_logic_vector.

I am using float_pkg library from ieee_proposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do:

```
type aftype is array (0 to 10,0 to 10) of float64;
signal af: aftype;
```

Then there's no conversion.

In terms of conversions, the `to_float` function requires a type to know how to format the `real` input:

```
signal f : float64;
f <= to_float(12.34, f);
-- or
af(0,0) <= to_float(12.34,f);
```

If you *must* have a std_logic_vector, you can use `to_std_logic_vector` from the package (aliased to `to_slv`):

```
a1(0,0) <= to_slv(to_float(12.34,f));
```

Comment: sure.. i am not sure how i do that.but i just clicked on the icon under the downvote button.is that how you accept the solution?

Comment: Note that the `f : float64` just for the size is not necessary. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17780987/119527).