# Convert real to IEEE double-precision std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)

Tags: floating-point, vhdl, ieee-754

This really shouldn't be this difficult.

I want to read raw 64-bit [IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) data from a file, and use it in a `std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)`.  I'm using ModelSim ALTERA 10.1b.

I tried to just read the raw binary data into the 64-bit vector:

```
type double_file is file of std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
file infile1: double_file open read_mode is "input1.bin";

variable input1 : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0) := (others => '0');

read(infile1, input1);
```

But this doesn't work.  Apparently ModelSim tries to interpret each *byte* of the input data as a `std_logic` (`'U'`, `'Z'`, `'-'`, etc.).  [image]

---

I can however, successfully read the data into `real` variables:

```
type real_file is file of real;
file infile1: real_file open read_mode is "input1.bin";

variable input1 : real;

read(infile1, input1);
```

But at this point, I **cannot** figure out how to convert that `real` variable to a `std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)`.  Pretty much all of the [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=vhdl%20convert%20real%20to%20std_logic_vector) just say "you can't do this; `real` isn't synthesizable".  I completely understand that - this is just for simulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the [`ieee.float_pkg`](http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/Float_ug.pdf).

First, you use `to_float` to convert the `real` to a floating-point:

```
variable in1_r : real;
variable in1_f : float64;

in1_f := to_float(in1_r, in1_f);  -- in1_f passed for sizing
```

Then, you simply convert the `float64` to an slv:

```
variable in1_slv : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);

in1_slv := to_std_logic_vector( in1_f );
```

This can also be done with a one-liner, eliminating the intermediate `float64`:

```
in1_slv <= to_std_logic_vector( to_float(in1_r, float64'high, -float64'low) );
```

The key there is that `to_float` needs to know the target size. Since we don't have an intermediate `float64` value, we can just pass the `exponent_width` and `fraction_width` parameters directly, using the definition of `float64`.  Looking at the definition of `to_float64` helped.

This question was of some help: [IEEE Float type to std_logic_vector conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482333/ieee-float-type-to-std-logic-vector-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

If all you're interested in is the 64 bit binary value of a 64 bit real representation, read them as characters and convert the value to std_logic_vector slice at a time and concatenate the slices into a 64 bit std_logic vector.  Note you'll have to pay attention to byte order and get the bit order right too.  It's as they say implementation dependent.  You're effectively treating the binary representation in the file being read as a union between a 64 bit FP representation and an array of 8 bit characters length 8.  Just make sure you always read all the characters for each 64 bit value.

See Edwin Narosk's 2004 reply to someone asking about  [character to std_logic_vector](http://computer-programming-forum.com/42-vhdl/db373c650ff562ce.htm) conversion.  The link Mr. Narosk provided in 2004 is not valid but can be found here:  [4.2.21 How to Convert Between Enumeration and Integer Values](http://www.eda.org/comp.lang.vhdl/FAQ1.html#enum_integer).  It simply doesn't have vi (for VHDL International) in the link path any longer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I finally managed to find a way to *actually* convert a `real` to an IEEE754 `std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)`.

Comment: "I want to read raw 64-bit IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point data from a file". The range of a real is implementation defined (package standard).  The above file input reading a file of type real isn't guaranteed to  represent your double-precision floating-point, it's a non-portable assumption. And yes you can express a real that's not a double precision floating point value as one by conversion.  It's not raw though.

Comment: Thanks David. I understand the implementation-specific issues with reading `real` from a file. However, I was given the shell of a testbench that was reading/writing `real`s from the file, and didn't really want to mess with all of that. So converting `real` to slv seemed the best choice here - this was for an isolated homework project though, and I would definitely go with a better solution for a more permanent and less time-crunched scenario.